# Send email after insert in Database

Tags: php, mysql, database

i'm trying to send email, when people complete the form in my website.

So, i have a HTML form, when you submit the form, you receive a Sweet Alert message confirmation, and the data its inserted on database, works OK that part, But I want, when the customer fills out the form, in addition to inserting it in the database, send an email to me with the info of the data that he filled out.

I don't know what is wrong, it is normally inserted in the database, but it simply ignores the email code, nor does any error return.

```
 <?php

 if(isset($_POST['save']))
 {
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];

   $nif = $_POST['nif'];
   $morada = $_POST['morada'];
   $distribuidor = $_POST['distribuidor'];
   $loja = $_POST['loja'];
   $online = $_POST['online'];
   $oficina = $_POST['oficina'];
   $outro = $_POST['outro'];
   $mensagem = $_POST['mensagem'];
     $sql = "INSERT INTO formdistribuidor (name,empresa,email,telefone,nif,morada,distribuidor,loja,online,oficina,outro,mensagem)
     VALUES ('$name','$empresa','$email','$telefone','$nif','$morada','$distribuidor','$loja','$online','$oficina','$outro','$mensagem')";
   if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {


  echo '<script>Swal.fire(
  "Obrigado pela sua mensagem!",
  "Responderemos o mais breve possível",
  "success"
)</script>';

if ($name != '' && $email != ''  && $morada != '')
 {
   $msg = '<strong>Nome:</strong> $name<br>';
   $msg .= '<strong>E-mail:</strong> $email<br>';
   $msg .= '<strong>Mensagem:</strong> $moradam<br>';
   $recipient = 'bruno@dga.pt';
   $subject = 'Contato Website';
   $header = 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n';
   $header .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n';
   $header .= 'From: $email\r\n';
}

} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "
" . mysqli_error($conn);

}

}

mysqli_close($conn);

 ?>
```

Thanks for your atention

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: There's no code here which would send an email. If you're just starting to work with email, I suggest using the free  [PhpMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) library to make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

You do not call the mail function

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```